# Що таке "первень"?

Tags: значення-слів

Наштовхнулась на статтю ["Трипільська культура – первень українського народного мистецтва"](http://www.aratta-ukraine.com/text_ua.php?id=90). Зацікавило слово "*первень*". Тлумачення цього слова у СУМі не знайша. У [цьому словнику](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&from=xx&to=ru&did=explain_words_uk&stype=)  є значення, яке не дуже відповідає зазначеній статті. Судячи з контексту ("Дошукуючись праоснов своєї нації, уважно проаналізував Трипільську культуру й дійшов такого висновку: ”Головний первень - трипільці”"), це щось, на зразок складника, складової. Але переконливого підтвердження цьому не знайшла. То що таке "*первень*"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Я думаю, що для вашого випадку підходить інше значення слова "первень". Його знаходимо на сайті [Горох](https://goroh.in.ua/%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C):

ПЕ́РВЕНЬ

> 1. Елемент, конструктивна частина.
> 2. **Першооснова, першоелемент чого-небудь.**

До того ж, корінь вказує на спорідненість з іншим [словом](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%8C)**:

ПЕ́РВЕНЕЦЬ, нця, ч., книжн.

> 2. чого, перен. Те, що з’явилося або **створено першим за часом**, раніше, ніж все наступне.

Тобто, моє припущення таке, що у статті малося на увазі:

"Трипільска культура - **основа (першопочаток)** українського народного мистецтва."

На доказ мого твердження наводжу цитату зі статті:

> “Від трипільців **починаємо** історію української території як одности і
>   її торгівельних взаємин з іншими країнами, одности духовної і
>   матеріальної”.

** Це підтверджує й етимолоґічний словник української мови у 6т:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

На [Офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/e/element/28-1-0-4825) знайшла таке:

> Синонiмі до слова **ЕЛЕМЕНТ**:(хемічний) у. **первень**; (системи) складник, інгредієнт, деталь, риса, аспект; (електричний) батерія, гальванічний елемент, сов. батарея; мн. ЕЛЕМЕНТИ.

Тож цілком ймовірно, що первень - це елемент (складова частина).
Тому, якщо замінити це слово на йому синонімічні, отримаємо: "Трипільська культура як складова частина / елемент українського народного мистецтва".

Натрапила ще у статті Івана Лучука ["Українські та єврейські первні в російській поезії першої третини ХХ ст."](http://www.ji.lviv.ua/n8texts/luchuk.htm) на це слово, де автор пояснює його, проте ще й інтерпретує:

> Слово "**первень**" мало б означати: **начало**, **первоначало**. В такому розумінні хотілося б пристосувати його до даного сюжету (начало ж вживається тут в значенні: **основа**, **суть**, **джерело** чогось там).

Проте сумніваюся, що саме друге значення підійде до контексту, пропонованого Вами. Тож варто залишити слово "первоначало".

Щодо академічних праць, то, на жаль, не знайшла нічого.

Answer (score 4):

[Українсько-англійський словник 1955р.](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&dicts=8&highlight=on) ([К. Андрусишин, Я. Крет](//e2u.org.ua/dicts/andrusyshen))

> **пе́рвень** (-вня) m Chem. element, constituent part.

[Англійсько-українсько-англійський словник наукової мови (фізика та споріднені науки). Частина І англійсько-українська 2010р.](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&dicts=4&highlight=on) ([О. Кочерга, Є. Мейнарович](//e2u.org.ua/dicts/4))

> **element** 1. елеме́нт || елеме́нтний 2. складни́к, елеме́нт, компоне́нта, складова́ части́на 3. (х.) хемі́чний елеме́нт, **пе́рвень**; про́ста речовина́ 4. (мех.) ла́нка 5. (техн.) елеме́нт констру́кції, ву́зол, блок 6. (ел.) (ґальвані́чний) елеме́нт, (первинне) джерело́ стру́му 7. (мн.) заса́ди, осно́ви 8. стихі́я

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C&scope=all&dicts=10&highlight=on) [[інфо](//r2u.org.ua/html/announcement.html)]

> **Начало**
>
> 7. (химич. элемент) елеме́нт (-та), первень;

Тут всюди вказують на *хімічну* складову — **елемент**. Тому тут теж може бути складовою, в такому собі переносному значенні.